# How to control the main panel width in Shiny App during collapse and expand?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a `shiny` app with side bar and main panel where on clicking the toggle button, sidebar collapses and main panel expands (width also increases). But when I try to click the toggle button again the main panel width stays the same with Sidebar expanded and Main panel underneath the Sidebar.

Example Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  tags$style(HTML(
    "#mainPanel {
       background-color: blue;
       color: white; 
    }"
  )),
  titlePanel("Toggler"),
  tags$div(id = "sidebar",
           sidebarPanel(
             bs_accordion(
               id = "accordion"
             ) %>%  
               bs_set_opts(
                 use_heading_link = TRUE
               ) %>%  
               bs_append(
                 title = tags$div(tags$i(class = "fa-solid fa-upload"),"Upload"),
                 content = fileInput("upload", "Upload a Excel File", 
                                     accept = c(".xlsx",".csv"))
               ) ,
             use_bs_accordion_sidebar()
           )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    id = "mainPanel",
    actionButton("toggle_btn", "Toggle"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2) # Upload file Size Limit (100mb)
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle_btn, {
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "sidebar")
    
    if (input$toggle_btn) {
      runjs('$("#mainPanel").css("width", "100%");')
    } else {
      runjs('$("#mainPanel").css("width","20%");')
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result:

[image]

I want the main Panel to return back to its original position along with width on toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` condition on `input$toggle_btn` won't work. You can put a boolean value which measures the state of the button inside an `reactiveValues` and change this state when the toggle button is clicked. Also we edit the `CSS` such that the formatting will return to the original style.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    
    tags$style(HTML(
        "#mainPanel {
       background-color: blue;
       color: white; 
    }"
    )),
    titlePanel("Toggler"),
    tags$div(id = "sidebar",
             sidebarPanel(
                 bs_accordion(
                     id = "accordion"
                 ) %>%  
                     bs_set_opts(
                         use_heading_link = TRUE
                     ) %>%  
                     bs_append(
                         title = tags$div(tags$i(class = "fa-solid fa-upload"),"Upload"),
                         content = fileInput("upload", "Upload a Excel File", 
                                             accept = c(".xlsx",".csv"))
                     ) ,
                 use_bs_accordion_sidebar()
             )
    ),
    mainPanel(
        id = "mainPanel",
        actionButton("toggle_btn", "Toggle"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2) # Upload file Size Limit (100mb)
    
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        stopApp()
    })
    
    bln <- reactiveValues(hidden = FALSE)
    
    observeEvent(input$toggle_btn, {
        shinyjs::toggle(id = "sidebar")
        
        if (!bln$hidden) {
            runjs('$("#mainPanel").css("width", "100%");')
            bln$hidden <- TRUE
        } else {
            runjs('$("#mainPanel").css("width","66.66%");')
            bln$hidden <- FALSE
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The toggle acts weirdly with content inside the main panel. On expanding collapsing the the content inside sometimes expand to match the width of main panel but sometimes it doesnt

Comment: Not clear what is meant due to missing examples. Also note that your `mainPanel` inside the question only contains an `actionButton` and therefore your question is answered. If you have a new question, you can ask it separately.